# Angular unit test case failing with "NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Environment!" error while testing a service to be truthy

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Getting error while trying to test the service, details of error-

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken
>   Environment]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken
>   Environment]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Environment!

Not sure where I am going wrong.

I have tried the importing the HttpClientTestingModule but it did not work, giving in the details of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Service.spec.ts file-**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed,inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController  } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { SummaryLevel, GuideLevel } from '@pm-web/pm-latte/data-interfaces';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        ExistingTradeSummaryFacadeService,
      ],
    });
  });


it(`should create`, async(inject([HttpTestingController, ExistingTradeSummaryFacadeService],
  (httpClient: HttpTestingController, apiService: ExistingTradeSummaryFacadeService) => {
    expect(apiService).toBeTruthy();
})));
```

I am getting the error described above, not sure what to do now.

Angular unit test case failing with  "NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Environment!" error while testing a service to be truthy

Comment: show us the component where u have used `InjectionToken`  (`@Inject`)

Comment: Imports-     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as _ from 'lodash';
   import { ExistingTradeSummaryStateService } from './state/existing-trade-summary-state.service';
    import { SummaryLevelApiService } from '@pm-web/pm-latte/data-api';
 
   import { SummaryLevel, GuideLevel } from '@pm-web/pm-latte/data-interfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

Comment: Not in the comments. Update your question with component code